# Expected an expression

Tags: c++, sfml

been playing around with sfml and game game programming for a while, but i am "expected an expression"

here is my code
.h file

```
    #include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

    using namespace std;

    class TileSet
    {
    public:
    TileSet(int firstTile, int tileWidth, int Tileheight, string filename );
    sf::Texture* GetTileSet() const;
    int FirstTileNo();
    int TilesCount();

    private:
    sf::Texture tileset;
    int firstTileNo;
    int tilesCount;
    };
```

.cpp file

```
    #include "TileSet.h"

    TileSet::TileSet(int firstTile, int tileWidth, int tileHeight,
             string filename):firstTileNo(firstTile)
    {
    tileset.loadFromFile(filename);

    int tilesInWidth = tileset.getSize().x / tileWidth;
    int tilesInHeight = tileset.getSize().y / tileHeight;

    tilesCount = tilesInWidth * tilesInHeight;
    }

    sf::Texture* TileSet::GetTileSet() const
    {
    return tileset* ;
    }
```

the error points to the "return tileset*;" statement

Comment: well yeah. what do you expect `titleset*` to do? it's a syntax error.

Comment: if you want to return the address of `tileset`, use `&tileset`.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention i tried that "&tileset" and and i got that "error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'const sf::Texture *' to 'sf::Texture *'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wimmel is correct in his comment. You need to change `tileset*;` to `&tileset;` This will return a pointer to your `tileset`

EDIT:
should be `return &(const sf::Texture)tileset;` but I'm not sure if that's what you want. I'm not a C++ expert and const correctness is not my strong suit, so I might do some more research on const correctness just to make sure that's what you really want or not.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention i tried that "&tileset" and and i got that "error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'const sf::Texture *' to 'sf::Texture *'

Comment: That's because your function is GetTileSet() `const` I'll edit my answer

Comment: I would still suggest looking into const correctness. There's another way to do what you're trying to do, which I assume is passing a pointer to the tileset and make sure whoever gets that pointer cannot modify the object. You can change your function to `const sf::Texture& TileSet::GetTileSet() const` and return `tileset` with no modifiers. This is just a starting point for you http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness